# Compile a Python 2.7 program that uses tktable

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, py2exe, pyinstaller, tktable

I have a program which uses a `tkinter` GUI along with the `tktable` module (I use it to display the results of a SQL query). It works fine when running it as a `.py` file, but compiling it into a `.exe` results in an *error with the program not being able to locate `tktable`*.

I am using `pyinstaller` to make my `.exe` and I know that `tktable` is **not on the list of supported modules**. Is there a way to make this work? I made an attempt to use `py2exe` as well using the following code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

options = {'py2exe': {
       'packages': ['pyodbc','tktable'],
       'includes': 'decimal',
       'compressed':1,
       'bundle_files': 1,
       'dist_dir': "exe/dist/dir"
       'dll_excludes'  }}

setup(console=['<PYTHON FILE>'], options=options,zipfile = None)
```

but the compiled executable simply crashes (works fine for `pyodbc`, but not for `tktable`). Is there support out there for compiling the `tktable` module to be used with an executable?

Comment: How did you make tktable work without installer?

Comment: tktable was installed on my development system so running a .py file that uses it worked fine. My issue was attempting to deploy the same .py file as an executable and still use tktable. IIRC I never got that to work.